# Error left-hand-side-of-an-assignment-must-be-a-variable

Tags: c#, vb6

I am currently converting from Vb6 to C# where the below Vb6 code is allowed :

```
Private Property Let gUnit(Optional bResolve As Boolean, aNoseHi)
    gNoseLo(Optional parameter) = 0  
End Property
```

Not Allowed:

```
void Test()
{
    gNoseLo(false) = 0   //error occurs here
}
```

The `gNoseLo` has been defined in VB6 as `Private Property Get gNoseLo(Optional bResolve As Boolean)`. I cannot use a public property approach in C# since there are parameters so I used a method. What would be the correct way to recode the `gNoseLo` to accept value assignment and prevent the error?

Comment: Pass the value as an extra argument?

Comment: And do you *really* need the argument? What is it for? What does the function do? Maybe you should think about a redesign while you're translating the code?

Comment: The original VB6 must not look like that because that isn't even valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A "property with a parameter" in C# is an *indexer*. You can't give it a name like you can in VB though<sup>1</sup>. You declare it like this:

```
public int this[bool parameter]
{
    get { ... }
    set { ...}
}
```

Now that may or may not be appropriate for your use case. Alternatives are:

- Have a regular property that *returns* something with an indexer:

  ```
  public class IndexedByBoolean
  {
      public int this[bool parameter]
      {
          get { ... }
          set { ...}
      }
  }

  public class ContainsPropertyIndexedByBool
  {
      private readonly IndexedByBoolean index;

      public IndexedByBoolean NoseLo { get { return index; } }
  }
  ```

  Then you could use `foo.NoseLo[true] = 0`
- Use `Get` and `Set` methods:

  ```
  SetNoseLo(true, 0);
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, you specify a name, but not use it *by* that name.

Comment: John Skeet, I appreciate the help! Thank you.